# How to perform text concatenation in object variables in PHP?

Tags: php, class, string-concatenation

If I use a "dot" to assign a value in a variable in a PHP class, it fails.

For example:

```
class bla {
       public $a = 'a' . 'b';
}
```

How should I approach this otherwise?

Comment: as @MrSmith notes below, this is now possible in php 5.6+

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only do that in the constructor, as class variables/properties must be initialized on declaration with constant expressions. From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

This means you can't use any operators or function calls.

```
class bla {
    public $a;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = 'a' . 'b';
    }
}
```

Comment: Needless to say, if it's really the letters a and b together, `public $a = 'ab';` will do, but I doubt that's the point of the question.

Comment: Note that you can't do this in a class that is used as a container of static methods, as you will likely never instantiate it. You could run an init() method for each method in said class that uses these constants.

Comment: @BoltClock : lol no that would not be the point of the question :)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying the exact same thing:

```
class someClass{
    public $var = APP . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "someFolder";
}
```

This however worked on my local machine but not on the server. After cursing for over an hour and not finding a clue I remembered that my local machine had a newer version of XAMPP installed and thus a different PHP version. So it seems that in PHP version 5.5.11 this was not possible but in version 5.6.8 you can actually combine strings.

I just installed the new XAMPP version on the test server to see if this is really true.

Comment: Just tried this and I can verify that it's true.  Thanks for the tip.